# Yii with bootstrap.?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I am trying to bind bootstrap with yii,downloaded a package from here. http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/,Have gone through the steps provided there,but its not working for me.

[image]

I have the following file structure.

my config/main.php is like .

```
<?php


// uncomment the following to define a path alias
 Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.

return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'My Web Application',

    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'),

    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
    ),
         'theme'=>'bootstrap', // requires you to copy the theme under your themes directory
    'modules'=>array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'12345',
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
        ),

    ),




    // application components
    'components'=>array(
        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        ),

                    'bootstrap'=>array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
        ),
        // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
        /*
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
        */
        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
        ),
        // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database
        /*
        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdrive',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
        */
        'errorHandler'=>array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),
        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ),
                // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
                /*
                array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                ),
                */
            ),
        ),
    ),

    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
    ),
);
```

I have a main layout in view but I am not able to see the page.
Here is the code.

```
<?php /* @var $this Controller */ ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="language" content="en" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/css/styles.css" />

    <title><?php echo CHtml::encode($this->pageTitle); ?></title>

    <?php Yii::app()->bootstrap->register(); ?>
</head>

<body>

<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar',array(
    'items'=>array(
        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
            'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
                array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
                array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
                array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
            ),
        ),
    ),
)); ?>

<div class="container" id="page">

    <?php if(isset($this->breadcrumbs)):?>
        <?php //$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbBreadcrumbs', array(
            //'links'=>$this->breadcrumbs,
        //)); ?><!-- breadcrumbs -->
    <?php endif?>

    <?php echo $content; ?>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div id="footer">
        Copyright &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> by My Company.<br/>
        All Rights Reserved.<br/>
        <?php echo Yii::powered(); ?>
    </div><!-- footer -->

</div><!-- page -->

</body>
</html>
```

I have an index page which I am getting without any css or menu.

view.php

```
<?php

/* @var $this SiteController */
$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name;
?>

<?php $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbHeroUnit',array(
    'heading'=>'Welcome to '.CHtml::encode(Yii::app()->name),
)); ?>

<p>Congratulations! You have successfully created your Yii application.</p>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

<p>You may change the content of this page by modifying the following two files:</p>

<ul>
    <li>View file: <code><?php echo __FILE__; ?></code></li>
    <li>Layout file: <code><?php echo $this->getLayoutFile('main'); ?></code></li>
</ul>

<p>For more details on how to further develop this application, please read
    the <a href="http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/">documentation</a>.
    Feel free to ask in the <a href="http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/">forum</a>,
    should you have any questions.</p>
```

I am not getting the desired layout...may be above information not sufficent to answer my question,will provide additional information if asked.

Comment: all are ok . did you try on any view page?

Comment: just edited ny question..have a look

Comment: its not loading main.php

Comment: Put this code <?php Yii::app()->bootstrap->registerAllCss(); ?> with in <head> tag in main layout hope will work

Comment: I am alredy using  Yii::app()->bootstrap->register.but still i have tried,,,but not working

Comment: did you put registerAllCss

Comment: try clearing assets folder

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52009/discussion-between-saji-and-ronit-adhikari)

Answer (score 1):

Also add bootstrap in preload:

```
'preload'=>array('log','bootstrap'),
```

Answer (score 0):

adding to @Ronit Adhikari answer, I don't remember very well, but I think there was a line like

```
Yii::app()->bootstrap->register();
```

and you had to put it in where you wanted to use, like in the main layout.

Comment: yah @tinybyte if you have multiple themes than this is useful